# Wireless Card seems to be slowing down Computer responsiveness

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a Windows 7 Desktop 3.something ghz quadcore with 8 gb of RAM. I just purchased a new wireless router, and whenever my computer's wireless card is turned on, the computer slows, the mouse jumps and windows move erratically when I move them. I have no other processes running. I turned off a lot of the wireless card features such as ipv6 and network sharing, helped a bit. Overall, it is still really slow whenever the wireless card is on. I have no issue with any of my other laptops / devices, just the desktop.

Comment: Name and shame that bad vendor. What brand card? What 802.11 chipset vendor's chips is it running?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the latest network drivers for the wireless card and see if that helps.
Also make sure Windows 7 has been updated through windowsupdate.com

Comment: Yup, all up to date, still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

So the new router was broadcasting in Mixed B,G,N. The wireless card on the computer was N as well. When the computer was running fine before, it was a only B & G. I switched the router to be only B & G, and it worked.

The slowdown was video playback only, not affecting computer resources, so I assumed it was the vid card. The wireless card is installed directly under the video card. Could it be that when it was broadcasting and receiving in N mode that it was interfering with the video card?

Either way, forcing it back to G seemed to make everything work just fine.